# Is there a ScenarioContext in WebdriverIO- how do we set a value to a key and then use this data across test scenarios?

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

Is there a ScenarioContext in WebdriverIO- how do we set a value to a key and then use this data across test scenarios?
I would like to do something like this using WebdriverIO- Java script-

```
 public ScenarioContext(){
        scenarioContext = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
 
    public void setContext(Context key, Object value) {
        scenarioContext.put(key.toString(), value);
    }
 
    public Object getContext(Context key){
        return scenarioContext.get(key.toString());
    }
 
    public Boolean isContains(Context key){
        return scenarioContext.containsKey(key.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you please explain without java examples?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2475987/mike-g- I want assign a value to a variable in one cucumber scenario, then do set context (store a value to a variable) and then get context (or fetch the value of the stored variable) in another cucumber scenario

Comment: Each feature file runs in it's own process, to share data between them you can use https://webdriver.io/docs/shared-store-service.html

Answer (score 1):

So you want a variable to have a value which can be shared between scenarios and edited between scenarios.

If yes, then please look at the https://webdriver.io/docs/shared-store-service.html

WDIO team have came up with module to achieve your task.

There is one other way as well:
In your `beforeSession` hook on `wdio.conf.js` file, you can define a global variable like `global.scenarioContext = {}`.

And now anywhere in your code(including stepDefinitions) you can access this variable as like `scenarioContext`(NOTE: do not prefix with `global.`) and assign value or read value or edit value.

Please let us know if this helps.

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Thank you @Naveen Thiyagarajan, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553424/naveen-thiyagarajan - i am getting an error when using https://webdriver.io/docs/shared-store-service.html , this is the error i get- Cannot read property 'set' of undefined   This is the code i used.......................................................     var EmailIdToBePassed = randomFirstName + '.' + randomLastName + '@gmail0.com'
        console.log('this is the email id-> '+ EmailIdToBePassed)
                this.inputUsername.setValue(EmailIdToBePassed);
        var EmailVal;
        browser.sharedStore.set(EmailVal ,EmailIdToBePassed)

Comment: You need to put shared store to the services list and install it, just follow the guide in doc

Answer (score 0):

I used the shared stored services and it solved my problem- https://webdriver.io/docs/shared-store-service.html
Additionally have to update the wdio.conf.js file to add the 'shared-store' in the services section like this-

```
 services: [
['selenium-standalone', {
logFileName: 'wdio-chromedriver.log', // default
outputDir: 'driver-logs', // overwrites the config.outputDir
args: ['drivers']
}], ['shared-store']
],
```